# How to replace substring of url without 301 redirect in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website that uses this structure: `http://mywebsite.io/blog-post/post.php?path=example` but I want users to be able to access this link with `http://mywebsite.io/blog/example`

So I am essentially trying to replace `/blog/` with `/blog-post/post.php?path=`

Right now I have this .htaccess file ...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

All this does is redirect me from `http://mywebsite.io/blog/post?path=example` to `http://mywebsite.io/blog/post.php?path=example`. So, it basically adds the extension.

I am not looking for a 301 redirect. I want this to quietly redirect users to the correct URL. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: At present what happens when you enter `http://mywebsite.io/blog/example` in browser?

Comment: Right now I am redirected to a "not found" page that I used earlier in my .htaccess using `ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php`. Also, a trailing slash is added to the url `http://mywebsite.io/blog/example/`

Comment: Is your directory named as `/blog/` or `/blog-post/`? Is there any other .htaccess?

Comment: The directory is named blog-post. The trailing slash is only added if there is a directory with name `example` in the folder `blog-post`. The other parts of the .htaccess just sets the DirectoryIndex and ErrorDocuments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/([\w-]+)/?$ blog-post/post.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: It works! How does it work though? Why is the first rewrite rule before the RewriteCond? What is the second RewriteRule for?

Comment: 1st rule is for handling `/blog/example` and 2nd rule is for adding `.php` extension.